# NameError: uninitialized constant CarrierWave::Storage::Fog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, fog, fog-aws

I have tried several solution given on stackoverflow and github, but couldnt find the solution. I am using **carrierwave (0.10.0)** and **fog-aws (0.8.1)** gems for my app to upload image to S3.

```
NameError: uninitialized constant CarrierWave::Storage::Fog
from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:73:in `eval'
from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:73:in `eval'
from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:73:in `storage'
from /home/pulkit/dev/roid/rails/appbrowzer/app/uploaders/publisher_action_icon_uploader.rb:11:in `<class:PublisherActionIconUploader>'
from /home/pulkit/dev/roid/rails/appbrowzer/app/uploaders/publisher_action_icon_uploader.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/pulkit/dev/roid/rails/appbrowzer/app/models/manage_channel_action.rb:3:in `<class:ManageChannelAction>'
from /home/pulkit/dev/roid/rails/appbrowzer/app/models/manage_channel_action.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from (irb):1
from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:9:in `require'
from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
```

And when i tried using the **fog(1.37.0)** gem instead of the **fog-aws** gem, then i am getting the different error.

```
ArgumentError:  is not a recognized provider
    from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/fog-core-1.35.0/lib/fog/core/services_mixin.rb:12:in `new'
    from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/fog-core-1.35.0/lib/fog/storage.rb:27:in `new'
    from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb:102:in `connection'
    from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb:356:in `connection'
    from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb:368:in `directory'
    from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb:261:in `store'
    from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb:80:in `store!'
    from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/store.rb:59:in `block in store!'
    from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:17:in `with_callbacks'
    from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/store.rb:58:in `store!'
    from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:375:in `store!'
    from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:207:in `store_icon!'
    from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:432:in `block in make_lambda'
    from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:228:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
    from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block in call'
    from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `each'
... 10 levels...
    from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
    from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
    from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
    from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:348:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:286:in `block in save'
    from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:301:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
    from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:285:in `save'
    from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:34:in `create'
    from (irb):1
    from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /home/pulkit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'2.3.0 :002 >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue by adding **Fog gem** in my Gemfile

```
gem 'fog', require: 'fog/aws'
```

Removed the configuration file from **lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb** as mentioned for [fog-aws gem](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#using-amazon-s3) and placed the carrierwave configuration in **config/initializers/carrierwave.rb**

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'XYZ',
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'ABC',
    :region                 => 'region'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'bucket_name'
end
```

Comment: its not working. the app getting configured to file storage but not to s3.

Comment: This is not the right solution. gem 'fog-aws' works. You just have to ensure carrierwave configuration is in config/initializers/carrierwave.rb

Answer (score 2):

Update your gemfile from **gem "fog-aws"** to **gem 'fog', require: 'fog/aws'**.

Comment: Now i am getting `ArgumentError:  is not a recognized provider`

Comment: This is not the right solution. gem 'fog-aws' works. You just have to ensure carrierwave configuration is in config/initializers/carrierwave.rb

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your configure file(carrierwave.rb) is in initializers folder.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the "fog-aws" gem?  I feel like I had a similar error for not following this section of the documentation: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#using-amazon-s3

Answer (score 0):

For me this was fixed by moving the `config.storage = :fog` after the `config.fog_credentials = ...` line in the Carrierwave initializer.

[via @mshibuya](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/2023#issuecomment-252407542)